# How to make my HashTable work on for a specific type

Tags: java, hashtable

I need to create a HashTable for a project.

Here is how I define what my HashTable is:

```
public class StudentHashTable<Name, DateOfBirth> {

}
```

The way you would create my HashTable is the following:

```
StudentHashTable<String,Integer> hashMap = new StudentHashTable<String,Integer>();
```

As it stands now, it would actually work for any object that has a key of String type and a value of Integer type. What do I need to think about so I can force the HashTable to only accept objects of type Student that has key of String type and value of Integer type?

Comment: What do you mean by "objects of type Student that has key of String type and value of Integer type"? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. First of all, you shouldn't define your own collections. Java has a standard HashMap. Use that. Second, tell us what you want to achieve, on a higher level. A HashMap of String, Integer doesn't care where the String and Integer come from. Maybe you should encapsulate the map into a class which deals with students, and uses a HashMap internally, without ever exposing this map to the outside.

Comment: I need to create my own for a project. I know Java has a built-in HashMap. My HashMap can only accepts Student object. A student has a key which is its name and a value which is its date of birth. I apologize for any prior confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your customized HashMap to **only** accept class Student, which is a very odd request as collections should be generic usually, then just do the following. make the setters only work with class Student.  This way you are guaranteed to not be able to accept anything except what you want.

Example:

```
public void put(Student student){...}

public void putAll(Student... students){...}
```

Comment: Yeah strange request from my professor. I will implement it that way.  Great help, greedybuddha!